# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when I change the format and location [SOLVE]

Tags: c#, wpf, location

**EDIT:** 
I write application who app need to read information from CSV file. This information is have date time format, double format. The columns is separate with ",". If the program is working with English format is working good, because the decimal symbol is ".". I try now with Germany format and I have exception ArgumentOutOfRangeException, because Germany decimal symbol is ",". My new question is: Can I used for decimal symbol to be "." without care what is format for computer.

Comment: How do you read from file? Try to set specific encoding

Comment: I used Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"); in correct place in the code and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < yValues.Count; i++)
    {
        ....
                averageValuesAndPixelsInYAxis.Add(yValues.Keys.ElementAt(i - 1)
```

At the first iteration `i = 0` and you are trying to access to element `yValues.Keys.ElementAt(i - 1)` with `-1` index

Comment: No If you see I check first Is to be possible. When is in English format is working perfect.